# Error while trying to free memory

Tags: c, memory, char, malloc, free

I'm take some errors trying free memory. A post all my code below.
I'm using ubuntu and I compile my code with gcc. But when I try execute my code I take an error while trying free memory.
I put comments on my code to explain my doubt. I'm working with stack structre.
How Do I free memory without take error to turn free memory for char?
If I whoud not free the memory allocated for the data (a char), and only to free the memory for the element (which contains the char data), which happens with memory allocated to the data? is it free?

### ERROR

```
{
    *** glibc detected *** ./pilha: free(): invalid next size (fast):      0x08b86018 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x74f82)[0xb7637f82]
./pilha[0x80485ba]
./pilha[0x804864c]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb75dc4d3]
./pilha[0x8048411]
    ======= Memory map: ========
}
```

---

**CODE**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct Stack_element{
    char *data;
    struct Stack_element *next;

}Element;

typedef struct Position{
    Element *top;
    int size;
}stack;

void start(stack *aux){
    aux->top = NULL;
    aux->size = 0;
}

int push(stack *aux, char value){

    Element *new_element;
    if ((new_element = (Element*) malloc(sizeof(Element))) == NULL)
        return -1; //an error occur
    if ((new_element->data = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char))) == NULL)
        return -1; //an error occur

    strcpy(new_element->data, &value);

    new_element->next = aux->top;
    aux->top = new_element;
    aux->size++;

}

int empty(stack *aux){

    if ((aux->size) == 0){
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;

}

char pop(stack *aux){

    Element *element;
    char value='0';

    if (empty(aux)){
        return '1';
    }


    element = aux->top;
    aux->top = aux->top->next;

    /*
        To observe the line below. When a element exist in the stack and
        I try remove this element, first I free the data in that node (element)
        so I turn free memory allocated for the element.
        If I didn't free data memory allocated before (in push fuction), I
        don't get any error. But the memory allocated for the data, what happens?
        Does is it continues allocated?
    */

    value = *(element->data);
    free(element->data);//THE ERROR OCCURS HERE, IN THIS LINE
    free(element);//Just after free the data element memory, I also free the element's memory

    aux->size--;
    return value;
}

int main(){

    stack p;
    char value;

    start(&p);

    //no error occurs. there isn't any element at this moment.
    printf("%c\n",pop(&p));

    //valor = 't';
    if (push(&p, 't')){
        printf("Add a char\n");
    }
    pop(&p);//the error occurrs now, after insert an new element in the stack
    printf("The End.");

}
```

Comment: Not related to your error but if your data is only one char why are you storing in a pointer?

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Answer (score 2):

In your code,

```
strcpy(new_element->data, &value);
```

is not correct. You have allocated memory for only one `char` which is not having space for null terminator. Instead you should use

```
*(new_element->data) = value;
```

Otherwise, with the improper usage of `strcpy()`, you'e messing up the allocated memory by making memory overrung which causes  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score -1):

At least this statement in function `push` is invalid

```
strcpy(new_element->data, &value);
```

You should write

```
if ( ( new_element->data = (char*) malloc( 2 * sizeof(char))) == NULL)
{
    free( new_element );
    return -1; //an error occur
}

new_element->data[0] = value;
new_element->data[1] = '\0';
```

Or

```
if ( ( new_element->data = (char*) malloc( sizeof(char))) == NULL)
{
    free( new_element );
    return -1; //an error occur
}

*new_element->data = value;
```

Function empty looks strange. Usually -1 is returned from a function when some error occurred. As for the function empty then neither error can occur. So it is better when the function returns 1 if the stack is empty. I would write it like

```
int empty( stack *aux )
{
    return aux->size == 0; 
}
```

Also it is not clear why function pop returns character '1' when the stack is empty. It would be better if it returns simply '\0'. So instead of

```
char pop(stack *aux){

    Element *element;
    char value='0';

    if (empty(aux)){
        return '1';
    }
    //,,
```

I would write

```
char pop(stack *aux){

    if ( empty( aux ) ) return '\0';

    Element *element;
    //,,
```

Comment: hello there, tanks for advances, but I make some mistakes because I translate my code to English, originally I write it in Portuguese. My concern is about free memory error.

Comment: the answer contains several undesirable coding statements, like using 'sizeof(char)'  when that value always 1, so no need to use that phase and casting the returned value from malloc and no need to 'free() a memory area when the malloc failed

Comment: @user3629249 If malloc failed you have to free previously allocated memory. As for other your remarks then they are simply silly. Take into account that I also can down vote your answers.